# Want to do some actions, when bar code is scanned in edit text in android

Tags: android

I am developing android pos application, where I'm using a barcode scanner which inserts barcode string into an `EditText` in the format like "89003169", "890142143" etc. Once the barcode is scanned and inserted into the edit text, I want to get the barcode value and search in database to get its price, and display it.

I have tried to add `addTextChangedListener` for the `EditText`. But the `afterTextChanged` method is called with each subsequent character of the barcode. (e.g. if bar code is "89003169", `afterTextChanged` method is called with values like "8", "89","890",...etc till the barcode ends)

The length of barcode string is not fixed. So, I am not able to determine when I got the complete barcode (so that I can get the price associated with the barcode).

Is there any way to get the complete barcode and perform the action, once scanning is done?

Thanks in advance,

Krishna

Comment: number of charecter in barcode is fixed or varying?

Comment: i dont think you need a trigger like textchnagedListener . you can simply get the text from edittext

Comment: Yes, I can get text from edittext. But what I want to do is, as soon as the scanned barcode is set in the editbox,  i want to get the barcode and perform search price and display price action. So I need  a callback once the barcode is scanned and displayed in edittext.

Comment: Number of character in barcode is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the search action when you set the text to textview. like this:

```
barTextView.setText(bartext);
searchAction(barText);

private void searchAction() {
   new Thread(new Runable{
     @Override
     public void run() {
         //do search action 
          //the post the result to ui thread
      } 

   })
}
```

if any question, pls re.